# GWT adding jar instead of project

Tags: gwt

Until now I added 2 projects to my GWT projects build path and inherited them in the gwt.xml, to use their classes. Everything worked well.

Then I tried to deploy the gwt project to tomcat and therefor, I needed to make a .jar file of both project and add these to the build path. But now I am getting errors.

```
 Compiling module com.wn.webapp.WebApp
   Validating units:
      Ignored 17 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/laura.eckardt/workspace/WebApp/src/com/wn/webapp/client/ServiceCalls.java'
         [ERROR] Line 24: The import com.wn.retail cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 25: The import com.wn.retail cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 26: The import com.wn.retail cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 27: The import com.wn.retail cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 28: The import com.wn.retail cannot be resolved
         [ERROR] Line 187: LaneContact cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 187: The type new AsyncCallback>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncCallback>.onSuccess(List)
         [ERROR] Line 187: LaneContact cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 196: The method onSuccess(List) of type new AsyncCallback>(){} must override or implement a supertype method
         [ERROR] Line 196: LaneContact cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 214: LaneStatus cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 214: The type new AsyncCallback(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncCallback.onSuccess(LaneStatus)
         [ERROR] Line 214: LaneStatus cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 223: The method onSuccess(LaneStatus) of type new AsyncCallback(){} must override or implement a supertype method
         [ERROR] Line 223: LaneStatus cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 343: LaneContact cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 350: LaneStatus cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 386: Request cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 390: InquiryHolder cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 419: The method setCurrentRequest(Request) from the type Lane refers to the missing type Request
         [ERROR] Line 420: The method setCurrentInquiry(Inquiry) from the type Lane refers to the missing type Inquiry
         [ERROR] Line 424: LaneStatus cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Line 429: The method setTransactionEntries(Transaction) from the type ItemList refers to the missing type Transaction
         [ERROR] Line 436: InputMethodHolder cannot be resolved to a type
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.wn.webapp.client.WebApp'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

What went wrong now?

Comment: Are your libraries in  your `war/WEB-INF/lib` where `war` is the top level folder for your app that you place in the `webapps/` folder in Tomcat?

Comment: yes they are. and i added them to the build path

Comment: Did you manage to run the project in Dev mode?

Comment: no, that's what i'm trying at the moment and were the error comes from

Comment: I think you should try importing your project into Eclipse (if it isn't already), download the GWT Eclipse plugin and then run it in dev mode from there. GWT will take care of setting up the server and you'll be able to troubleshoot more easily. Also, you won't need to create any jars.

Comment: i already did this. i always programmed with gwt plugin and i imported the projects and all worked fine. but now i need to run it on tomcat and therefor i cant just add the projects to the buildpath. do u know what i mean? so... i added the jars instead of the projects and cant run the project anymore

Comment: I get it now. You have to make sure that the `.java` files are included in your jar, not only the `.class` files.

Comment: thx. =) seems like a dumb failure^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your jar files you need to include the sources files (`.java`). To do so in eclipse you need to right click on your project and then select `Export` and then select the `JAR file` in `Java` folder. In the next screen check the "Export Java source files and resources" and then `Finish`.

Should work after you add it to your build path.